# Organizing code related to regular Django and DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a web site powered by Django, and a respective Django REST Framework (DRF) Api for communicating data to outside world (say, Android). After doing a research, I came to a conclusion that REST framework's endpoints should not be used for rendering regular Django templates (used for rendering the website itself). So I have two sets of urls and views for the the same collection of ORM models. And the question is,

1. what is the best practice to name the DRF urls and regular urls, so that I do not confuse which one is used for web, and which one as endpoint for outside world
2. Should I define both DRF class-based views and regular views for rendering website in the same python file, or should I separate them?

To keeps things simple, imagine the project contains only one model.

```
class sms(models.Model):
    # fields
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sms'
```

Now, I have two sets of views for this model (the DRF):

```
class SmsList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    # template_name = 'sms/incoming_list_paginator.html'

    def get(self, request):
        qs = SMS.objects.all()
        serializer = SMSSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and regular view for rendering the respective webpage:

```
def get_sms(APIView):
    qs = SMS.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('test.html',               
                              {'legal_entities_form':legal_entities_form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now, I have two urls which I would ideally like to name 'sms'. But I have to name them differently, like, `sms` and `sms_rest`. What is the best practice? Is it ok if I, say, add `_rest` suffix to all DRF-related urls ?

Comment: Hi Edgar :) Again!

What about namespaces in urls? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

So at the end you will have: `cms:sms-list` and `rest:sms-list`;

Happy coding!

Comment: If you are trying to integrate a website with DRF, I would **strongly** suggest to use Angular 2. That way, you can separate the website's frontend from the backend and simply continue connecting with your current REST api and not add even more server code to the backend to handle a dedicated website.

Comment: Good point about namespaces. As for Angular.js, I need time to make further research into this. Thanks for comments. Apoorv, could you please provide a bit more details which could help in research this?  Perhaps a recommended link?